# Expect script arrow keys

Tags: networking, tcl, expect, system-administration

I didn't know that how to send arrow keys using expect, hence I generated autoexpect script for all the arrow keys and found out that autoexpect generates this character for right arrow key:

```
send -- "^[\[C"
```

I used the same send command in my custom script and  I'm getting a following error:

```
while executing
"send -- "^[\[C"
expect eof
"
    (file "script_auto.exp" line 38)
```

What exactly shall I do to send the right arrow key. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sending ^ [ or escape?   It should be escape-[-C.

Comment: I only typed right arrow and checked the script generated by autoexpect.. Above mentioned command was generated by autoexpect.

Comment: I have tried capturing the right arrow key and got `send -- "^[\[1;5C"`. Wondering why this difference. Anyway, can u try `send -- {^[\[C}` ?

Comment: It didn't give me any error but it didn't do the right click.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"^[\[C"` is an invalid string in `Tcl`. `^[` should be the `ESC` char which is `\033`. So try this:

```
send "\033\[C"
```

**UPDATE:**

The safest way to get the correct RIGHT ARROW key for current terminal (as in `$TERM`) is to use `tput`:

```
[bash] # v=$(tput cuf1)
[bash] # printf '%q\n' "$v"
$'\E[C'
[bash] #
```

To know what `cuf1` means, run `man terminfo` and search for it. :)

Comment: And to see all the arrow keys: man terminfo | grep "cursor_"

Answer (score 3):

For Arrow up key you have to send as shown below

```
send "\033\[A"
```

I have tested this