# How can I make down arrow key be effective in shell(or expect) script

Tags: bash, shell, expect, auto

I am writing scripts for automate 'make menuconfig'.
I want to use down arrow key to select some items in the dialog.
My down arrow key in terminal is '^[[B'.
So I use send "\033[B", send "\x1b\x5b\x42", send "\1B[B", etc. in expect script,
but none is working.

```
#!usr/bin/expect
spawn make menuconfig
send "v" #select item hot key
send "y" #enter this item
send "\033\[B" #I expect the down arrow key will execute here.
interact

exit 0
```

How could I do?
Or does this not work in expect?
Is there other method to automate do this?

Comment: From Review: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54398561/edit) your answer provide your current script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496136/expect-script-arrow-keys

Comment: I have provided it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I have tried it. But it does not work.

Comment: You may be sending `v` and so on before the program is ready for it. Put an `expect "xxx"` command before each send, where xxx should be one of the last things written before you would typically type `v`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I finally discovered the down arrow key is '^[OB' in the dialog. So I solved it using 'send "\033OB" '.